# Finding the corresponding polar graphs for the given function.

Tags: calculus

Below are plots of five polar curves

[image]

[image]

Which of the five polar plots corresponds to the Cartesian plot given above?

What confuses me here is if whether the second graph is in Cartesian form, but with polar coordinates, or something else. I tried to answer it as Graph's 1 and 
4, since their coordinates are $(0,2)$ and $(\frac{\pi}{2}, 0)$, just like the second picture's graph, but this comes up as incorrect. Am I seeing it the right way, or is their something else I'm missing? Any kind of guidance on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hint: When $\theta = 0$ then $r=2$ so a couple of graphs are out of the question already. All graphs are drawn in Cartesian plane

Comment: So would that take 2, 4 and 5 out of the equation, since their $\thetas$ are 0, their $r's$ never encounter 2? But I'm still a little confused. Aren't the first graphs in a polar plane, while the last graph is a cartesian plane with polar coordinates?

Comment: Your given graph is polar: $r$ as a function of $\theta$ The graphs you have to choose from are Cartesian. The correct translation is the essence of this exercise. So graph 4 is a strong contender because of the hint I gave earlier

Comment: I see it now. I was having a difficult time understanding the type of graphs that were given, but thank you.